# PostgreSQL, how can i populate this table which has two foreign keys as it's fields

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a problem when trying to populate a table using a script using the psql terminal window and the -f option (this executes the script).

I can populate the piste and lift tables fine no problems at all, but i have another table which contains foreign key's to these tables. I can create the table fine, but i cannot add anything to the table, i simply have no idea how to do this.

My tables:

```
piste {piste_name {PK}, grade, length, fall, open}
lift {lift_name {PK}, lift_type, summit, rise, length, operating}
lift_location {piste_name*{PK}, lift_name*{PK}}
```

My script:

```
CREATE TABLE piste (
    piste_name varchar(30) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    grade varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    length decimal NOT NULL,
    fall smallint NOT NULL,
    open boolean NOT NULL

);

CREATE TABLE lift (
    lift_name varchar(20) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    lift_type varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    summit smallint NOT NULL,
    rise smallint NOT NULL,
    length smallint NOT NULL,
    operating boolean NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE lift_location (

    piste_name varchar(30) REFERENCES piste(piste_name),
    lift_name varchar(20) REFERENCES lift(lift_name),
    PRIMARY KEY(piste_name, lift_name)
);
```

so if i insert some values into these tables:

```
INSERT INTO lift (lift_name, lift_type, summit, rise, length, operating) VALUES
('test lift', 'gondola', 1920, 440, 1600, true);


INSERT INTO piste (piste_name, grade, length, fall, open) VALUES
('test piste, 'medium', 3, 440, true);
```

These tables will one row with the specified information. based on the above i want my lift_location table to have the following information:

```
piste_name | lift_name
________________________
test piste | test lift
```

How can i accomplish this?

Thanks.
Chris.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run an additional query. You need add a new row to the `lift_location` table to create the relationship between the two rows in the two tables.

```
INSERT INTO lift_location (piste_name, lift_name) VALUES ('test piste', 'test lift');
```

Also make sure both `lift` and `piste` tables have the required test data. You're missing a `'` in your second `INSERT` query.

Comment: ye sorry that was a typo! so i just insert into it the same way? thanks.

Comment: @chrisedwards Yes, there's nothing special about the `INSERT`. The constraint is primarily useful for maintaining ["referential integrity of your data"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/tutorial-fk.html), so that, for instance, you can't create a relationship between a piste and list to a lift that doesn't exist.